# DevExpress Reports different watermark image on 2 pages or alternative?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, devexpress

I am creating a report with DevExpress in VS2013 and I need to create it according to a template. The report consists of 2 pages which need to display an image of a page from a PDF en then display data accordingly.

In my first attempt I created 2 report with their according watermark images and then added the second report to the first programmatically.

```
 if (reportModel.Report is RequestBonusPage1)
        {
            var tweedePagina = new RequestBonusPage2();
            secondPage.CreateDocument();
            reportModel.Report.Pages.AddRange(secondPage.Pages);
        }
```

If I create the report this way the data needed to display on the second page doesn't get passed, hard coded labels are. Also the watermark image itself is not displayed even though I have the DrawWatermark property set to true.

With my second attempt I removed the watermark image from the second page and added the image with a Picturebox but the labels with the data are then displayed next to the picturebox. I used this link (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q323059) as an example for doing this.

Does anyone how I can make these examples work or know any alternatives as of how to achieve this?

If anything is unclear about my explanation don't be afraid to ask.

Kind regards

EDIT:

```
public ActionResult ExportDocumentViewer()
    {
        var reportModel = BuildReportModel(ModelSessionHelper.CurrentReportData);
        ProcessSpecificReport(reportModel);
        return DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DocumentViewerExtension.ExportTo(reportModel.Report);
    }

    private static void ProcessSpecificReport(ReportModel reportModel)
    {
        reportModel.Report.CreateDocument();
        if (reportModel.Report is SalesReport)
        {
            var secondPage = new SalesReportPage2();
            secondPage.CreateDocument();
            reportModel.Report.Pages.AddRange(secondPage.Pages);
        }

        if (reportModel.Report is RequestBonusPage1)
        {
            var secondPage = new RequestBonusPage2();
            secondPage.SetReportData(reportModel.ReportData);
            secondPage.DrawWatermark = true;
            secondPage.CreateDocument();

            reportModel.Report.Pages.AddRange(secondPage.Pages);

            CreateWatermarkRequestBonus(reportModel);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateWatermarkRequestBonus(ReportModel model)
    {
        model.Report.Pages[0].AssignWatermark(new Watermark
        {
            Image = Properties.Resources.bonus_request_page_001,
            ImageViewMode = ImageViewMode.Zoom,
            PageRange = "1",
        });
        model.Report.Pages[1].AssignWatermark(new Watermark
        {
            Image = Properties.Resources.bonus_request_page_002,
            ImageViewMode = ImageViewMode.Zoom,
            PageRange = "2",
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Page.AssignWatermark`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingPage_AssignWatermarktopic) method to set the watermark for particular page.
Here is example:

```
var report = new YourReportClass();

//...

report.CreateDocument();

var page = report.Pages[0];

var watermark = new Watermark();
watermark.Text = "Watermark text";
watermark.TextDirection = DirectionMode.ForwardDiagonal;

page.AssignWatermark(watermark);

report.ShowRibbonPreview();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, at this moment I have it like that but the problem is I can only use those settings in a specific controller that's used for all reports and that code doesn't belong there because it's specifically for this one report. If I try the same code on the report itself I get an Index out of bounds exception because pages aren't built yet.

Comment: @Gravinco Can you add your code to your question and provide more details? What is a specific controller?

Comment: By specific controller I mean a certain controller, in this case the one that is used to display reports. If I try to add the code to the controller that builds the data for the report I can't get it to work (Code is in question)

Comment: @Gravinco There are no code about how your are displaying your reports.

Comment: I was still editing the question, you were here faster than expected :-p

Comment: @Gravinco The pages must be builded after `YourReport.CreateDocument()`. If not, then there some problems with `DataSource` of your report.